# Laravel: Combine Partially Duplicate Objects In Array

Tags: php, laravel

Here is a array of object I have and it has some objects with partially duplicated object values. What I want to do is to combine partially duplicated object into one object with their respective different values also included.

```
[
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Instruments",
        "Cash": "3000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "Cash": "2000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "KBZPay": "8000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-23",
        "expense_detail": "Stationary",
        "Cash": "1500"
    }
]
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
[
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Instruments",
        "Cash": "3000",
        "total": "3000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "Cash": "2000",
        "KBZPay": "8000",
        "total" : "10000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-23",
        "expense_detail": "Stationary",
        "Cash": "1500",
        "total": "1500"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far and explain what is not working.

Comment: how did you get the 1st array of object? Perhaps you may handle this when you are making the first array. Completely agreed with @AlexHowansky, if you don't show us what you have tried we can not help much.

Answer (score 0):

You make try use [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique) & [combine](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-combine) method in collections. In your example I think like that for example:

```php
$firstCollection = collect([
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Instruments",
        "Cash": "3000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "Cash": "2000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "KBZPay": "8000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-23",
        "expense_detail": "Stationary",
        "Cash": "1500"
    }
]);

$secondCollection = collect([
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Instruments",
        "Cash": "3000",
        "total": "3000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-20",
        "expense_detail": "Phone Bill",
        "Cash": "2000",
        "KBZPay": "8000",
        "total" : "10000"
    },
    {
        "clinic_id": "1",
        "expense_date": "2021-08-23",
        "expense_detail": "Stationary",
        "Cash": "1500",
        "total": "1500"
    }
]);

$combined = $firstCollection->combine($secondCollection);
$uniqueItems = $combined->unique();
```

Comment: I only have one collection not two. What I want to achieve is to combine objects with same 'expense_detail' property. In my problem there are two objects with same 'expense_detail : Phone Bill '. I want something like this
{ 
  "clinic_id" : "1",
  "expense_date" : "2021-08-20",
  "expense_detail" : "Phone Bill",
  "Cash" : "2000",
   "KBZPay" : "8000",
   "total" : "10000"
}

Comment: You try to use the filter method to get only the same objects and combine source with filterable collections.